sort OrderedDict by value then key
I would like to arrange OrderedDict A as follows :
A = OrderedDict({'a': 7, 'h': 6, 'c': 11, 'cc': 11, 'm': 9, 'n': 11, 'g': 7, 'b': 5.0, 'k': 11})

Expected result
A =  OrderedDict({'c': 11, 'cc': 11, 'k': 11, 'n': 11, 'm': 9, 'a': 7, 'g': 7, 'h': 6, 'b': 5.0})

The sorting should be based on the value at first, and if there are equal values, then the equal values ​​should be sorted based on the key as in the example above.
I used
OrderedDict(sorted(A.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1],x[0]),reverse=True))

but the result was not desired:
OrderedDict({'n': 11, 'k': 11, 'cc': 11, 'c': 11, 'm': 9, 'g': 7, 'a': 7, 'h': 6, 'b': 5.0})

corrected by :
OrderedDict(sorted(A.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1],x[0]),reverse=False))

Obviously, you reversed the whole comparison so you compare by value descending and key descending. Since the value is a number you can just sort normally, but using the negation of the value (-x[1]). This will sort values descending and keys ascending.

Does this answer your question? Sorting a dictionary by value then by key
